# Changing CA for a website

Tags: https, security-certificate

As an AWS user I am currently thinking about breaking up with my current Certificate Authority in favor of AWS ACL due to ease of maintenance for the latter (just for the sake of accuracy).

What actually is about to happen: certificate i use for my website will be replaced with new one issued by another CA.

I just need to know what negative consequences i will face in term of security, SEO and user expirience of my clients.

Comment: There is absolutely no evidence to support the idea of Google rewarding differently depending on which CA is used, in fact the SEO benefit from enabling SSL is so tiny, most webmasters notice no gain at all. In terms of security, you would need to include details of the CA that you have and the one that you about to have, but the trust comes from whom is issuing it and not actually the code within CRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes of certificates happen all the time (and even more now with newer CAs like Let's Encrypt that gives 90 days validity for certificates), and this can be a change of CA too, it will be mostly transparent to anyone as long of course as the new CA is installed as root certificate in all clients.

Some advanced users (for example the CertPatrol extension of Firefox) or online tools may detect the change when they store the previous certificate and see it has changed.

You may have problems however if you use DANE or CAA records in your DNS zone, as these things will need to get updated properly when you change the chain of certificates.

And if you feel curious or need numbers, this case would be ideal for an A/B test: you decide to provide x percent of time the old certificate, and for the rest the new certificate and you compare results for users of your site.